# VBA Coding in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am very new to VBA Coding. I have **two sheets** in excel .

Sheet 1 - Columns include CTC ,TCC (A1,B1)
          Rows contain the ctc and tcc details (A2,B2)

Sheet 2 - Rows include CTC and TCC. It's in this page that TCC Calculated.
          B1 has CTC taken from first row of sheet1.Then calculations are done to calculate TCC in B3.

**Requirement :**
For calculating TCC ,we need to paste the first CTC in sheet 1 to sheet 2 CTC Column.The result obtained has TCC should appear on sheet 1 under TCC Column.

**This is the code I tried :**

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim value1 As Integer
    Dim value2 As Integer

    For i = 1 To 6

        value1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("Ai").Value

        Sheet2.Range("B1") = value1

        Sheet1.Cells(B, i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("B3").Value

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code? Does it give an error (if so, what error, where)? Does it just not run? Does it run, but not output what you expect? ...

Comment: I assume "Sheet 1" and "Sheet 2" are the **names** of your worksheets, as they contain spaces.  What are the codenames of each of them (i.e. is `Sheet1` the codename of "Sheet 1" or of "Sheet 2")?  Also, which sheet is the first one (i.e. `Sheets(1)`) and which is the second one?

Comment: "Ai" doesn't look like a valid range.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that this code is what you want.
Let me know if it's different that what you expected.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim value1 As Integer
    Dim value2 As Integer
    For i = 1 To 6
        value1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value ' we can't make Range("Ai").Value
        Sheet2.Range("B1").Value = value1
        Sheet1.Cells(i, Range("B1").Column).Value = Sheet2.Range("B3").Value 'Cells(row, columns), that is the correct format for cells
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, You can replace -> Range("B1").Column <- with 2
I wanted to make it clear only.

Comment: OK - I wasn't sure whether you were using that method simply because you thought it was a useful way of doing things when you were using Cells with a column of, for instance, "DHA" - and didn't realise that you could just use `"DHA"` instead of `2913`.

Comment: `Cells(5, "DHA")` is the same as `Cells(5, 2913)` which is the same as `Range("DHA5")` - the second parameter of `Cells` can be a number or a String.  (I was using "DHA" as a "for instance", i.e. as an example.)

Comment: Sorry - I keep forgetting that people might still be using older versions of Excel - it's valid in Excel 2007 and later.  Maximum column in Excel 2003 is column "IV".  So your version might allow `Cells(5, "IV")` (equivalent to `Cells(5, 256)`) but not `Cells(5, "IW")`.

Comment: (And it's possible that the ability to use a string for the column wasn't introduced at all until Excel 2007, so even `Cells(5, "IV")` may not work in Excel 2003.  [Excel 2007 documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841096.aspx) states that the ColumnIndex is a Variant representing "the column number of the cell you want to access, starting with either 1 or "A" for the first column in the range", so definitely available from 2007 onwards.)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the following code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 6
        ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet 2").Range("B1").Value = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, "A").Value
        ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, "B").Value = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet 2").Range("B3").Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

I've used sheet names of "Sheet 1" and "Sheet 2", as that is what you have in your question.  Those should be changed if your sheets are actually called "Sheet1" and "Sheet2".

---

It's hard to know how close you were without knowing which `CodeName` your sheets were using, and which order they appeared in the workbook.  But your use of a `Range("Ai")` was definitely wrong - it needs to be `Range("A" & i)` or `Cells(i, "A")` (or `Cells(i, 1)`).

---

Updated to process **all** values in column A of worksheet "Sheet 1":

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet 1")
        For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            'Check so that we only process non-empty cells
            '(just in case there is an empty cell part-way through the data)
            If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i, "A").Value) Then
                ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet 2").Range("B1").Value = .Cells(i, "A").Value
                .Cells(i, "B").Value = ThisWorkbook.WorkSheets("Sheet 2").Range("B3").Value
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I will try the above codes.I have not named my sheets yet.Its still the default name.The error thrown is method or data memeber not found.

Comment: @Archa If the sheets are still the defaults, you have (by default) named them "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" - update the code to change "Sheet 1" to "Sheet1" and "Sheet 2" to "Sheet2".

Comment: thank you so much .It worked ! can I use a while loop to stop it when cell is  blank?

Comment: @Archa You can use a `While` loop, or you can modify the `For` statement to just run until the last non-empty cell.  I prefer to use `For` loops myself because they automatically increment the row number, which you have to remember to write yourself when using a `While` loop.  (I have put myself into an infinite loop so many times due to not remembering to do that!)  I updated the answer to show how to change the `For` loop to go to the last cell, with an extra test to skip any empty cells found before the last non-empty cell.  (That then allows you to have breaks in your data if you want.)